# c++ templates - combining deduction with default template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple class ([details here](https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/c6d09c9f42c475eb7d49a357e4c2f612d38e6338/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Cache/Memoizer.h))

```
namespace MemoizerSupport {
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    using DEFAULT_CACHE = LRUCache<T1, T2>;
}

template <typename RESULT, template <typename, typename> class CACHE = MemoizerSupport::DEFAULT_CACHE, typename... ARGS>
struct Memoizer {
    Memoizer (const function<RESULT (ARGS...)>& f, CACHE<tuple<ARGS...>, RESULT>&& cache = CACHE<tuple<ARGS...>, RESULT>{});

    nonvirtual RESULT Compute (ARGS... args);

private:
    function<RESULT (ARGS...)>    fFunction_;
    CACHE<tuple<ARGS...>, RESULT> fCache_;
};
```

usable as follows:

```
unsigned int totalCallsCount{};
Memoizer<int, MemoizerSupport::DEFAULT_CACHE, int, int> memoizer{
    [&totalCallsCount](int a, int b) { totalCallsCount++;  return a + b; }
};
VerifyTestResult (memoizer.Compute (1, 1) == 2 and totalCallsCount == 1);
VerifyTestResult (memoizer.Compute (1, 1) == 2 and totalCallsCount == 1);
```

My problem is that I want to be able to have the 'default cache' object DEFAULT, and to deduce the other parameters:

```
// doesn't work
Memoizer  memoizer{[&totalCallsCount](int a, int b) { totalCallsCount++;  return a + b; }};
```

I know I can replace the argument definition for the Memoizer template with a 'typename FUNCTION' to allow about anything to match, but
then I don't get the deduced types which I need for the cache.

And I'd like to be able to put DEFAULT_CACHE argument at the end of the typename name (in the Memoizer template), but then
I cannot have the template be variadic in the number of arguments to the memoizer?

Is this something C++ templates just don't support yet, or is there some hint/pattern someone can offer to make this work a little more smoothly??

```
Thanks,
      Lewis
```

Comment: Hi Lewis, this is an interesting question.  But it's really more about programming than engineering and therefore should belong to StackOverflow

Comment: @Christophec thx. I'll try there. I'm still a little fuzzy on the distinction